# Debug WPF Project as process inside a WinForm solution

Tags: wpf, winforms, debugging, child-process

I have a C# solution with multiple WinFrom projects, and in this solution, I have a WPF project also.
When I start a WinForm project as a process inside MainProject, it runs perfect and I can debug it without any problem. But when I want to start WPF project as a separate process inside MainProject, I can't debug it.
I use Child Process Debugging Extension for debug child processes.
My code for start child process :

```
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UI.Export.DTO.Launcher)).Location,
                WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UI.Export.DTO.Launcher)).Location),
                Arguments = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(launcher))),
            });
```

I also add both WinForm and WPF projects to Child Process Debugging Settings!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how do you mean "I can't debug it"? Does it enter debug mode without hitting the breakpoints?

Comment: Debugger Menu-> Attach to the process

Comment: @Bizhan No, the code create process but breakpoints in WPF process doesn't hit!

Comment: @Rekshino I want to see what happen in startup of WPF project. With Attach to process I loose that method.

Comment: Does it mean the breakpoints icons are empty red circles? In this case it means the symbols are outdated and you need to compile the WPF again

Answer (score 1):

I would

- subscribe an `Application.Startup`
- put a blocker to the event handler of `Application.Startup`
- do attach to the process, while wpf application is hanging in the
  blocker part.

```
public partial class YourWpfApp : Application
{
    public YourWpfApp()
    {
        Startup += YourWpfApp_Startup;
    }

    private void YourWpfApp_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);//Attach to the process, while waiting here.
        Startup -= YourWpfApp_Startup;
    }
}
```